# "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object.."

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, fatal-error

Following error occures:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

The code:

```
class Guestbook {

    public $db;

    public function getEntries(){
        $result = false;
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY id DESC'; 

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query); //error in this line (17)                               
        // ...
    }   
}
```

Comment: You class variable $db is undefined. Included file doesn't affect it. P.S. This is extremely bad design ...

Comment: $this->db is not equal to $db in the database connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this class:

```
class Guestbook {
    public $db;
```

You never give the `$db` property a value, so when you do

```
$this->db->prepare($query);
```

You're basically doing

```
null->prepare($query);
```

Give `$db` a value in the class constructor (or make sure it's passed into the class somehow, either way..) and you'll be fine.

The

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'guestbook');
```

In the database connection has no relation with the `$db` variable in the class unless you pass it into the class or make the database-initialization happen within the class.